# How can I smooth a rough plaster finish?

Tags: plaster, render

We have the kind of plaster in the images below on our inside dining room walls.
We want to change it to a smooth finish - presumably with drywall and plaster.
I don't know what this current finish is, it was put up by the last owner.

Do you think it would be feasible to remove it with an SDS or should we just batton over it?
I have heard that using an SDS will be messy and time consuming.
However, if it came off in chunks it might be doable.
The room is 3x4x2.4m.

Many thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A skim coat might be quicker, easier and cleaner...

Comment: I've heard I could use a thistle coat first and then skim. Would that work, I wonder?

Comment: texture aside, it looks pretty sloppy in the top pic, might be worth drywall just to get sharp clean edges, unless that's part of the charm, like in a fairy house.